# How do I use code to generate a graph where the line crosses the origin in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to use Matlab to generate a line graph, but the line terminates at the last point, and doesn't go all the way to the origin. Is there any way to make it so that the line goes beyond the points in code?

I've attached the code that I'm currently using, along with pictures of what the graph looks like right now and how I want it to look.

[image: What the line looks like]

[image: What I want the line to look like]

```
%Enter Data
fnet = [0.465, 0.560, 0.670, 0.763, 0.870, 0.971, 1.063];
faccel = [0.434, 0.514, 0.612, 0.684, 0.776, 0.850, 0.915];
asys = [0.4963, 0.6034, 0.7074, 0.8088, 0.9210, 1.030, 1.138]
mh = [0.050, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11]
x = fnet;
y = asys;

%Model Equation
model = 'm*x'
%the model can be changed, ex. m*x^2
IV = 'x'
DV = 'y'

%Create and perform curve fit
newfit = fittype(model, 'Independent', IV, 'Dependent', DV);
%result and goodness of fit, prime symbol converys rows to columns
[result, gof] = fit(x', y', newfit, 'StartPoint', 1)

%plot fits and data points, create plot object for formatting
p = plot(result, x, y);

%style the data points
p(1).MarkerSize = 10;
p(1).Marker = '.';
p(1).MarkerFaceColor = 'blue';
%p(1).MarkerEdgeColor = 'green';

%style the line of best fit
p(2).LineWidth = 1;
p(2).Color = 'black';

%Create graph object, set formatting to latex
graph = gca;
set(graph, 'defaultTextInterpreter', 'latex');
set(legend, 'visible', 'off');

%format title and subtitle
graph.Title.String = {'System Acceleration vs. Net Force on System', 'in Modified Atwood Machine'};
graph.Title.FontSize = 16;
%subtitle, where we will place our equation and statistics
%specifically, the equation w/ units, r squared, slope with plusminus %
graph.Subtitle.Interpreter = 'latex';
graph.Subtitle.String = '$a_{sys} = 1.064 m^{-1}F_{net}, \, r^2=0.9994, m=1.064 \pm 0.007$';
graph.Subtitle.FontSize = 13;


%format x and y axes
graph.XLabel.Interpreter = 'latex';
graph.XLabel.String = '$F_{net} \: (N)$';
graph.XLabel.FontSize = 15;
graph.XLim = [0,1.5];
graph.XGrid = 'on';
graph.XMinorGrid = 'on';
graph.XMinorTick = 'on';

graph.YLabel.Interpreter = 'latex';
graph.YLabel.String = '$a_{sys} \: (\frac{m}{s^2})$';
graph.YLabel.FontSize = 15;
graph.YLim = [0,1.5];
graph.YGrid = 'on';
graph.YMinorGrid = 'on';
graph.YMinorTick = 'on';
```

Comment: Just draw another line on top without markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `plot` directly on the fit `result` object, you can call `plot` with a bit more control and evaluate the `result` directly for the line

Replace this:

```
p = plot(result, x, y);
```

with this:

```
hold on
p(1) = plot( x, y );
p(2) = plot( [0,2.2], feval(result, [0,2.2]) );
```

Note you could add the marker and line options during the `plot` calls now if you wanted, instead of updating `p(1)` and `p(2)` in retrospect.